# Is it possible to change colors in serilog?

Tags: .net, logging, .net-core, themes, serilog

I have just integrated Serilog in my dot net core project. It is working really well but I use a dark theme and some logs are really dificult to read. As an example:

[image]

This is how I init Serilog:

```
string environment =  Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        
LoggerConfiguration loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration();
            
if (environment == "Production")
    loggerConfig.MinimumLevel.Information();
                
loggerConfig.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore",
    LogEventLevel.Warning) 
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.File("Logs/app.log");
```

Is there any way I could change colors to make that black logs white for example?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, the way to change colors when using the Console sink is through [themes](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-console#themes). You can try one of the built-in ones, or create your own.

The Console sink will colorize output by default:

[image: Colorized Console]

Themes can be specified when configuring the sink:

```cs
    .WriteTo.Console(theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Code)
```

The following built-in themes are available as of this writing:

- `ConsoleTheme.None` - no styling
- `SystemConsoleTheme.Literate` - styled to replicate *Serilog.Sinks.Literate*, using the `System.Console` coloring modes supported on all Windows/.NET targets; **this is the default when no theme is specified**
- `SystemConsoleTheme.Grayscale` - a theme using only shades of gray, white, and black
- `AnsiConsoleTheme.Literate` - an ANSI 16-color version of the "literate" theme; we expect to update this to use 256-colors for a more refined look in future
- `AnsiConsoleTheme.Grayscale` - an ANSI 256-color version of the "grayscale" theme
- `AnsiConsoleTheme.Code` - an ANSI 256-color Visual Studio Code-inspired theme

Adding a new theme is straightforward; examples can be found in the [`SystemConsoleThemes`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-console/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.Console/Sinks/SystemConsole/Themes/SystemConsoleThemes.cs) and [`AnsiConsoleThemes`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-console/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.Console/Sinks/SystemConsole/Themes/AnsiConsoleThemes.cs) classes.

Comment: why is "nblumbhardt" colored blue in the screenshot

Comment: @ThomasAdrian All string *log event properties* are colored in teal by default; numbers in purple.