# Serilog - How to perform logger.Information("string") with Colors?

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

I'd want to output on console some `_logger.Information("text")` with colors

e.g if logs message starts with `Success` then write it with green color

Does anyone have an idea whether this could be achieved without writing your own, new sink?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to change colors in serilog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62953942/is-it-possible-to-change-colors-in-serilog)

Comment: Hi, @Sinatr I've seen that but I'm not exactly sure how I'd have to apply that custom rule `if logs message starts with Success then write it with green color`

Comment: I don't think, that you can do that without creating your own color schema

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> if logs message starts with Success then write it with green color

The only way to achieve that today is to **write your own custom version of the [`Console sink`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-console)**. You'd have to implement your own [`ThemedMessageTemplateRenderer`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-console/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.Console/Sinks/SystemConsole/Rendering/ThemedMessageTemplateRenderer.cs).

[`Serilog.Sinks.Console`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-console) [allows you to define colors through Themes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62955743/211672), but you can only define colors for a set of known kinds of information such as `string` or `boolean` values from properties, or general text, for example. You can see the [full list of supported `ConsoleThemeStyle`s in the source code](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-console/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.Console/Sinks/SystemConsole/Themes/ConsoleThemeStyle.cs).

Here is an example of how you would create a custom theme using [`Serilog.Sinks.Console`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-console). In this example, text is displayed in green, and strings in yellow.

[image: screenshot of example custom theme running]

```
var customThemeStyles =
    new Dictionary<ConsoleThemeStyle, SystemConsoleThemeStyle>
    {
        {
            ConsoleThemeStyle.Text, new SystemConsoleThemeStyle
            {
                Foreground = ConsoleColor.Green,
            }
        },
        {
            ConsoleThemeStyle.String, new SystemConsoleThemeStyle
            {
                Foreground = ConsoleColor.Yellow,
            }
        },
    };

var customTheme = new SystemConsoleTheme(customThemeStyles);

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console(theme: customTheme)
    .CreateLogger();

Log.Information("Good morning {UserName}!!!", "Augusto");
```